# How to find the unique element in XML and alter the value in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a huge XML with about 67K lines.
I don't know the exact value of the parameter.
I only know which `<Section>` contains the required `<Parameter>` and the unique name of it.

XML looks the similar:

```
<Configurations>

<Configuration type="A">
<Configuration type="B">
<Configuration type="C">
<Section name="A">...</Section>
<Section name="B">...</Section>
<Section name="C">
<Parameter name="a" value="1" />
<Parameter name="specialStuff" value="this" />
</Section>
<Section name="D">...</Section>
...
</Configuration>
</Configuration>
</Configuration>
...

</Configurations>
</Document>
```

How can I reach the `specialStuff` parameter and modify the value of that?

Comment: use an XML reader. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If beyond this sample case you actually need to change more than one value maybe consider using Xsl transformation instead.

Comment: At least you quantified it. Usually when people say they have a huge XML I have to ask whether they mean 100Mb or 100Gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using `XDocument` and `SetAttributeValue()`:

```
string xml = @"
             <Configurations>
                 <Configuration type=""A"">
                     <Configuration type=""B"" >
                         <Configuration type=""C"" >
                             <Section name=""A"" ></Section>
                             <Section name=""Bv"" ></Section>
                             <Section name= ""C"">
                                 <Parameter name= ""a"" value = ""1"" />
                                 <Parameter name= ""specialStuff"" value = ""this"" />
                             </Section>
                             <Section name= ""D"" ></Section>
                         </Configuration>
                     </Configuration>
                 </Configuration>
             </Configurations>";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
xdoc.Descendants("Parameter")
    .Where(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == "specialStuff")
    .FirstOrDefault()?
    .SetAttributeValue("value", "youNewValue");
```

This will change the `value` of first matched tag with name "Parameter" and `name` attribute `specialStuff`.

Method `Descendants()` returning the filtered element collection (with document order) in your xml, 
with given tag name.

If you have more `Parameter` tags with `name` attribute equals to `specialStuff`, you can get your collection, and modify them separately:

```
var specialStuffs = doc.Descendants("Parameter").Where(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == "specialStuff");
foreach (var item in specialStuffs)
{
    item.SetAttributeValue("value", "newValue");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\Yourxml.xml");

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement; 
string qry = "//Parameter[@name='specialStuff']"; 
XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode(qry);
node.Attributes["value"].Value = "newValue";

doc.Save(@"D:\Yourxml.xml");
```